# How to pass model to controller from view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

View

```
    <div id="model">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
               {
                 <span>File Name: @item.Name</span><br />
                 <span>File Name: @item.Path</span><br />
               }    
          </div>

  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Send(SendDetails details)
   {
     //some code here
   }
```

> How to pass model from view to the controller when clicking button
>   submit?

Comment: You need a form and your form needs to contain form controls with `name` attributes that relate to your model properties.

Comment: By using HTTPPost with a form in your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a form in your view and then submit it.

**View**

```
@model YourModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
     <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Send(YourModel model)
{
     //some code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm facing another problem, can i update the question and maybe you can take a look on it?

Comment: If it's related to this then sure, otherwise just post another question (you can link me to it as well if you would like?)

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
@model yourmodel (with path) then use form

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="myId">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
             <span>File Name: @Html.EditorFor(item=> item.Name)</span>
             <br />
             <span>File Name: @Html.EditorFor(item=> item.Path)</span>
             <br />
        }    
   </div>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
}
```